# the reason that the training loss does not change at all

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I have built the following model to perform sequence prediction, here is the model

```python
inputs = Input(shape=(64,1))
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64,12,activation='relu',input_shape= (64,1),padding='causal'))
model.add(Conv1D(64,12,activation='relu',padding='causal'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Conv1D(128,12,activation='relu',padding='causal'))
model.add(Conv1D(128,12,activation='relu',padding='causal'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dropout((0.5)))
model.add(Dense(dense_expansion,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss=loss_function, optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['mse','mae'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(X_val,Y_val), epochs=nr_of_epochs,verbose=2)
```

The model architecture is like this

[image]

However, the training result looks like there is no change, what are the possible reasons. The training data is of shape (1496000,64,1) and (1496000,1); the validation data is of (374000,64,1) and (374000,1).

[image]

Comment: From purely looking at your code, I have a question: why is the input shape (64,1)? It is equivalent as (64). Is your image actually 8x8? If so, it's better to reshape it to 8x8 and change the filter size for your conv2 as well.

Comment: Hi Yilun, the input is a sequence. I am performing conv1d over the sequence.

Comment: How is your loss function defined? Also among the most common errors that exhibit this kind of behavior are permuting the inputs with respect to the labels. I'd spend some time double checking that your data and labels are all ordered as you expect them to be.

Comment: loss function is  'mean_squared_error'